# “BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling @@ĀðăԁԜ㜈ܳ栍၊逖⩩뜬庐޵샐瀞쯖ﾣ뷌ﮖ隲徒?⭫먬ཋ鐖ܶ氎Ԟ㨈Ą"

Tags: android

I have multiple class extending Parcellable and I can't understand where is the problem.

Here you are the exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myPackage/myPackage.MyApplication}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: @@ĀðăԁԜ㜈ܳ栍၊逖⩩뜬庐޵샐瀞쯖ﾣ뷌ﮖ隲徒?⭫먬ཋ鐖ܶ氎Ԟ㨈Ą܁
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
Caused by android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: @@ĀðăԁԜ㜈ܳ栍၊逖⩩뜬庐޵샐瀞쯖ﾣ뷌ﮖ隲徒?⭫먬ཋ鐖ܶ氎Ԟ㨈Ą܁
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2295)
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableArray(Parcel.java:2338)
       at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2206)
       at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.getInt(BaseBundle.java:794)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:63)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:76)
       at myPackage.MyApplication.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:229)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

I can't reproduce this exception on my device.

Comment: Double check them to ensure that you are serializing them in the right order and using the right class loader.

Comment: I haven't any class called @@ĀðăԁԜ㜈ܳ栍၊逖⩩뜬庐޵샐瀞쯖ﾣ뷌ﮖ隲徒?⭫먬ཋ鐖ܶ氎Ԟ㨈Ą܁